# I need some help to write an sql query, I want to find all the instructors teaching courses

Tags: sql, database

There are 3 tables:

- Instructor (ins_id, ins_name)
- Course(c_id, c_name)
- Ins_teach_course (ins_id, c_id)

`ins_id` and `c_id` are foreign and primary keys.

I know that all the instructors teaching courses information will be stored in `ins_teach_course`, but I want to extract `ins_name` and `c_name` from that as well.

I have written this so far, is this correct?

```
select 
    i.ins_id, i.ins_fname, i.ins_lname, c.c_id, c.c_name
from 
    ins_reg i, course c
where 
    i.ins_id = (select ins_id from ins_teach_course) 
    AND c.c_id = (select c_id from ins_teach_course);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't look like a good way to get this information.  Think `join` in the `from` clause.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution may retrieve uncorrelated results between instructors and courses.
In order to correlate them, you could use a `join`:

```
SELECT i.ins_id, i.ins_name, c.c_id, c.c_name
FROM   instructor i
JOIN   ins_teach_course itc ON i.ins_id = itc.ins_id
JOIN   course c ON c.c_id = itc.c_id
```

Comment: what if I want to find the courses taught by an instructor with ins_id=123, where will be the "where clause" added?

Comment: @user3855999 after all the `join`s

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT I.ins_name, C.c_name
FROM Ins_teach_course IC
JOIN Course C ON C.c_id = IC.c_id
JOIN Instructor I ON I.ins_id = IC.ins_id
```